# mysql.so: undefined symbol: vio_blocking

Tags: linux-mint, mysql, ruby, rails

I'm trying to set up a Rails 2.2.2 installation (for an old app that I maintain) in a new Linux Mint 18 install.

I've installed mysql (`5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)`) and, using RVM, have installed the same mysql gems that I have in my old Linux Mint 13 install (which i still have up and running on a seperate partition on the same computer).

The gems are:

```
mysql (2.7)
mysqlplus (0.1.2)
```

When I try to start rails I get this error:

```
irb: symbol lookup error: 
/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@elearning-resource/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.so: 
undefined symbol: vio_blocking
```

I don't know what mysql.so is: it's a binary of some sort.

I've never seen this error before - can anyone help?

thanks, Max

Comment: `mysql.so` is a 'shared object', i.e. sort of function library. It seems that your version of RoR needs a different (newer?) version of `mysql.so`, having the symbol `vio_blocking`defined.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed mysql and installed an earlier version (5.6.16) instead and that fixed it.  I think that my version of the rails mysql gem may be too old for the latest mysql.